# Derivative of an integral with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I want to know how to calculate the derivative of this integral, assuming that all our functions are bounded and smouths on some interval of $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
F(x)=\int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)} f(x,t) dt
$$

Comment: http://www.econ.yale.edu/~pah29/409web/leibniz.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general formula is $$ F'(x) =\cfrac{d}{dx} \int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi (x) } f(x,t) dt = \cfrac{d \psi(x)}{dx} f(x,\psi(x)) - \cfrac{d \phi(x)}{dx} f(x,\phi(x)) + \int^{\psi(x)}_{\phi(x)} \cfrac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x} dt $$

For more: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), aka differentiating under integral sign: 
$$
F'(x)=f(x,\psi(x))\psi'(x)-f(x,\phi(x))\phi'(x)+\int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$

Answer (score 1):

The [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) states that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)dt=f(x,b(x))\frac{db(x)}{dx}-f(x,a(x))\frac{da(x)}{dx}+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial_x}f(x,t)dt$$
and so if we have:
$$F(x)=\int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)}f(x,t)dt$$
we get:
$$F'(x)=f(x,\psi(x))\psi'(x)-f(x,\phi(x))\phi'(x)+\int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)}f_x(x,t)dt$$